# Why does scrolling a UIWebView *feel* so much different than scrolling any other UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm building an app that loads in a *small* amount of simple HTML (locally) into a single full-screen UIWebView. I'm noticing that scrolling this web view *feels* significantly different than scrolling any other UIScrollView. This does not appear to be a performance or a responsiveness issue, per se... It's just a matter of how the momentum plays out as you drag and flick the web view up and down. It just doesn't feel very "native" (for lack of a better word). It's like scrolling through molasses or pudding... kinda "sticky" and not as "slick" as you would like it to feel.

Does anyone know what causes this? Is there any way to fix it, or at the very least make scrolling a UIWebView feel more "native"?

Comment: What sort of HTML are you displaying? Maybe there's a way to accomplish everything using native controls.

Comment: @JackLawrence - The HTML is actually user-generated, pulled from the server periodically, and stored in core data. I could theoretically implement the view with native controls, but it's not as flexible as displaying the user-generated data directly.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I have the same perception.  It must have to do with the webView's scrollView deceleration rate.  Just ran this test, and 1) it confirms our suspicion and 2) suggests a fix.

I added a scrollView and a webView to my UI then logged the following:

```
NSLog(@"my scroll view's decel rate is %f", self.scrollView.decelerationRate);
NSLog(@"my web view's decel rate is %f", self.webView.scrollView.decelerationRate);
NSLog(@"normal is %f, fast is %f", UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal, UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast);
```

The output confirms the guess about webView being more frictional:

```
my scroll view's decel rate is 0.998000
my web view's decel rate is 0.989324
normal is 0.998000, fast is 0.990000
```

And suggests a fix:

```
self.webView.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
```

Comment: Silky smooth. Just perfect. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that this is done because web views are much more expensive to render than most other views. Making the scrolling "stiffer" helps hide this by ensuring there's less new area to draw when the user scrolls. That's not to say you shouldn't change this if you know a particular web view can handle it, but keep in mind that it *is* being done for a reason and you should make sure it's not a problem for your use case.

Comment: This is fantastic! I hope it works for my project. Thank you.

Comment: @BrentRoyal-Gordon I just stumbled upon this question and i'm wondering: if `normal` scroll deceleration rate is `0.998000` and `fast` is `0.990000` which is lower than `normal`, then shouldn't the `webview` value of `0.989324` which is even lower than `fast` make the scroll even speedier instead of slower? That is, web views being more expensive to render, i would have expected a value larger than `0.998000` for the deceleration rate, not lower. Am i missing something?

Comment: Deceleration is an ambiguous term. It makes better sense if you think of it as the magnitude of negative acceleration. Probably applied as v' = v(1-r).

Answer (score 0):

### Jerky scrolling with WKWebView

I noticed unpleasantly rough un-smooth scrolling in an iOS app under development.  It was almost intolerable compared to scrolling a typical web page on an iPhone with a blazing fast CPU and GPU (Note: doing this under iOS 16.4 on an iPhone 14 Pro Max).

This was a distinct performance degradation I observed immediately after converting my app to use `WKWebView` (*instead of `UITextView` with `NSAttributedString` objects constructed from HTML*).

I think it's because, during scrolling, `WKWebView` is sending a lot of events over the wire back to XCode (the debugger).

The jerky scrolling movement was worse if I made font larger in the HTML text, or did expensive realtime layout operations like icorporating the CSS "text-align: justify;" in the HTML content.

---

### After unplugging the phone from XCode, and launching app untethered, the scrolling became smooth as silk!

---

*Note: It's not an issue during testing per se. It scrolls fast enough with the jerkiness, that it's fine during development, knowing the user will have a much better experience.*